# Link to view the edit history of a question

Tags: support, questions, edits, revisions-list

Is there a link on a question's page to see the edit history of that question?  What is the "normal" way to get this information?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just click on the time that shows how long ago it was edited...

> [image]

If you do not see a time for how long ago it was edited, that the current version is also the original post (thanks Pesto).

As of 5/22/13 the entire phrase "edited on month day at time" is now a clickable link, which should be a lot more intuitive.

Comment: Wow... since forever I just assumed you had to be a certain rep to see it because I didn't see a link and only now after another user with lower rep than me talking about viewing it did I find this when searching for how to see edit history.

Comment: When I edit my post almost immediately after posting it, I do not see the "edited" link. Does it not appear if I edit my own post, but only if others do? Or does it only show up when edits happen after a certain age?

Comment: @void.pointer a little late, but that's the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info).

Answer (score 12):

Just put the question number in where # is:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/#/list`

e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/3400/list

Comment: Not really a link on the page as requested, but useful information; thx.

Comment: Without scripting, asking this is asking users to go away.